# Calling python script utilizing matplotlib from java servlet

Tags: java, python, bash, servlets, matplotlib

I am trying to generate plots of data from a JSON file sent to a java servlet on a glassfish server. In the servlet I am trying to call a bash script that calls a python script to do the plots.

The bash and python scripts work fine if I log into the server and run them from the terminal but when called from the servlet they do not work. After some testing I believe the matplotlib import is what is causing the problem. If I remove code pertaining to matplotlib from the python script it will run successfully but with matplotlib code nothing happens and I get no errors.

Below is the servlet code:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = runtime.exec("./test.sh "+"122333333.JSON");
try {
    proc.waitFor();
 } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
   Logger.getLogger(FileRetrieve.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }

 InputStream inputstream = proc.getInputStream();
 InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
 BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);
 String line;
 while ((line = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
    out.println("\nOUTPUT = " + line);
 }
 out.print("\nbefore execute6");
 try {
   if (proc.waitFor() != 0) {
   out.println("\nexit value = " + proc.exitValue());
   } 
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
   out.println("\nERROR = " + e);
   }
```

Below is the bash script:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo this is a test from script
echo $1
python script1.py $1
echo this is another test from script
```

Below is part of the python script:

```
import json
import matplotlib as mpl
import sys
mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = sys.argv[-1]
if filename.find('.')==-1:
        begin = filename[:filename.find('.')+1]
else:
        begin = filename[:filename.find('.')]

json_data=open(filename)
data = json.load(json_data)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xlabel('time (ns)')
ax.set_ylabel('acceleration (m/s^2)')
ax.set_title('Acceleration X')
ax.plot(data['aTime'], data['ax'], linewidth=1.0)
ax.grid(True)
fig.savefig(begin+'ax.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure its the import then I would be willing to wager the problem is an import issue. There are a couple easy ways to test this. The first that comes to my mind would be, in your bash script, to su into your user before executing the script. It doesn't seem like a very secure permanent solution but it would verify it being a module loading issue.